# Is it possible to use AWS SES with application on HEROKU?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I'd like to use Amazon SES to send mail from my application deployed on Heroku

Currently I am able to send mail from localhost, but not able to send mails from my application deployed on HEROKU

Comment: you might want to add what you currently have (it works locally) if you dont want to get all the downvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason why it cannot work. Basically the steps are as follow

1. update your credentials to Heroku

   ```
   heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy AWS_REGION=region
   ```
2. update your Gemfile

   ```
   gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
   gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
   ```

Then `bundle install` to take into effect

3. configure Amazon SES to be your mail application, update `config/environments/production.rb`

   ```
   aws_credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'])
   Aws::Rails.add_action_mailer_delivery_method(:aws_ses, credentials: aws_credentials, region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])

   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :aws_ses
   ```

Then it should work

Comment: Thanks Frédéric.. it is working. I think the problem was with the Gemfile.

Comment: [Do I get Amazon SES Free-Tier Pricing when I send emails from Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41867307/242933)