# Do I get Amazon SES Free-Tier Pricing when I send emails from Heroku?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ses

According to the  [Amazon SES Pricing: Pricing Details: AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/#AWS_Free_Usage_Tier),

> If you call Amazon SES from an Amazon EC2 instance or through Elastic Beanstalk, you can send up to 62,000 email messages per month at no charge.

Is this also true if I call Amazon SES from my Heroku app, since it runs on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: Is this something that Heroku themselves could answer? - just a thought.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?

Comment: @halfer good call.

Comment: @DanielFlippance see below.

Answer (score 6):

I emailed this question to [support@heroku.com](http://mailto:support@heroku.com), and in less than 10 minutes, they replied:

> Unfortunately no.
>
> However, we do have 3rd party add-ons that offer mail sending, most
>   with free plans to start:
>   https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/email-sms
>
> SendGrid seems to be the most popular.